# Can we automate scheduled published/Unpublished nodes in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, cron

Schedular Module helps to schedule Nodes publish and un-published in Drupal 8. But it affect took place on each cron run only.

For example. If I set Publish a Node A on `19/10/16 14:30` but site configure to run cron after each hour. So it's get published on `14:00`.
Is their any way to make it publish on exactly `14:30`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Scheduler module has it's own cron: http://example.com/en/admin/config/content/scheduler/cron, so you can configure any granularity you need

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could also use the Ultimate Cron module, which allows you to configure the granularity for each cron hook separate. So you can run drupal cron every minute, and scheduler also every minute, but system cron only every 3 hours.